# xcdatamodel not compiling on the device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, device, xcdatamodel

I have my App.xcdatamodel file included in my project.  When compiling for the simulator, the App.mom file is generated and my core data manager finds it and runs.  When compiling and running for the device, the App.mom file is not generated.

The xcdatamodel is included in the Target Membership (checkbox is checked) and the xcdatamodel file is included in "Compile Sources" for the App's Target.

I have another xcdatamodel for the old version of the database.  It's included in the Target Membership and under "Compile Sources".  This old version of the database is working just fine, both the simulator and device runs always successfully generate the .mom file.